# Cursor size adjustment

Tags: mac, mac-pro

I have a mid 2010 Mac Pro and I would like to have a larger Pointer on my cursor so that I can find it easier. Where might I go to fine and download one?

Comment: A little more info is needed.  What OS  are you running? What do you mean by pointer?  The mouse arrow or the cursor in the the field when typing text ?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the cursor size in
System Prefs > Accessibility > Display

Alternatively, you could use the 'shake to locate' feature on the same page.

[image]